# Bash script never receives arguments when called from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: bash, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running a declarative Jenkins pipeline on Ubuntu 18.04 slave. My issue is that whenever I'm trying to provide arguments from a `sh` step to a bash script, the arguments are not there. When running the exact same commands from either a terminal directly or another script file (similarly how Jenkins does it via temp file) the arguments work fine.

The Jenkinsfile looks something like

```
pipeline {
    agent { label "ubuntu" }
    options { timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh """
                #!/bin/bash
                ...
                . ./Scripts/install_tools.sh "force"
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The pipeline itself runs smooth and does what I need it to do. The problem is that when calling `install_tools.sh` no arguments are found. The script looks something like

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running $0"
echo "Args: $@"

...
```

The line `echo "Args: $@"` I have tried also with `$*` and `$1` - Each time the arguments are returned as empty, but only when running from the pipeline. It seems to me that this is related to some Groovy stuff, but I have no clue what.

How do I call a bash script during the pipeline and get the arguments passed properly?

Comment: logic behind sh step is quite simple - create a temp file with content you have provided and run it. you could try to do it manually.

Comment: Maybe I should've mentioned that in the question, but yes, I created a temp.sh file where I copied the content of the step and the arguments were set fine. The issue persists only when running via Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `#!/bin/bash` into the first line

```
sh """#!/bin/bash
   . ./Scripts/install_tools.sh "force"
   """
```

otherwise . (dot) command could have different meaning

Comment: And here I thought that the line below **was** the first line.